# Speed of MIN/MAX vs GROUP BY for aggregating constant-in-group values

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

In the the table `T`, it is guaranteed that each value of column `A` is associated with exactly one value of column `B` (i.e. that there is a [functional dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) A → B).  Because of this both of the queries below return the same results.  Which one will generally run faster?

Using GROUP BY on `A` and `B`

```
select
   A
   ,B
   ,sum(C) 
from
   T
group by
   A
   ,B
```

or using MAX/MIN on `B`?

```
select
   A
   ,MAX(B)
   ,sum(C) 
from
   T
group by
   A
```

I do know that the GROUP BY `A` and `B` version is better at not concealing data issues where an `A` arrives that is associated with more than one `B`, I'm just curious about whether one of the queries is generally more work for a DBMS to execute.  If the answer depends entirely on the choice of DBMS and you still have interesting information to share then choose your favourite DBMS and answer only for it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Let's say MS SQL Server 2016...

Comment: Anyone who has experience with SQL Server probably knows enough not to guess stuff like this, and take both alternatives for a spin in the optimizer to find out what the answer is for their service pack/CU level/table size/available indexes/fragmentation/number of processors/query flags/statistics/phase of the moon (not necessarily in order of importance). My very general answer is going to be a very boring and unimaginative "it depends (but probably won't vary a whole lot, in most cases)".

Comment: I'd opt for the latter, because it makes more clear (to the future reader) that `A` will be unique in the result. What is going to impact performance is having a suitable covering index available... with A and B as the leading columns (in that order) and including column C. I'd expect similar performance from both queries, but if one turns out to be faster, my guess would be the second. To get a handle on performance, I would be taking a looking at the execution plan and measuring performance of both statements. (Performance is mostly going to depend on the plan using a suitable index.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I went ahead and ran a test on SQL Server 2016 even though I was interested in uncovering more general, theory-based information.  I used four columns in the role of `B` above to accentuate any differences in run time and submitted a batch containing both types of query above.  The execution plans generated by SQL Server were almost identical but the cost reported for the GROUP BY query was 53% of the batch while that of the MAX/MIN query was 47%.

The initial index seek step is identical for both queries.  It is followed by hash table building step in which the GROUP BY version incurs a higher cost than the MAX/MIN version.  The steps after that have negligible cost for both versions.

Counter-intuitively, in spite of the GROUP BY version having a slightly *higher* cost, it runs in slightly *less* time.  I guess it's still possible to consume more CPU cycles while running if parallelism is greater.  At this point I've reached the end of my ability (and appetite) to scry DBMS execution plans so I'll leave it there.